# React Native FlatList ListHeaderComponent wrapped in SafeAreaView doesn't respect the boundaries of SafeAreaView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, safeareaview

### Description

Hello, I'm pretty new to React Native and I was trying to render a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` and I got an error mentioning this application of `FlatList` inside `ScrollView` is not proper and it may cause some scroll disorientations. So, I searched for solutions to this problem and found out there's `ListHeaderComponent` property for `FlatList` to render everything else inside `ScrollView`. I accomplished implementing this solution to my screen but now It doesn't respect to boundaries of `SafeAreaView` which is pretty annoying, I don't want to add hard-coded margin/padding to the outer `ScrollView/View` component. It wouldn't be pretty.

### Current Implementation

**screens/Home.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';

import SearchBar from '../components/UI/SearchBar';
import CarouselSlider from '../components/UI/CarouselSlider';
import FeaturedProducts from '../components/UI/FeaturedProducts';
import RecommendedCategories from '../components/UI/RecommendedCategories';
import ProductList from '../components/UI/ProductList';
import { HeadingSecondary } from '../components/UI/Typography';

import CarouselSliderData from '../data/slider';
import MostSold from '../data/mostSold';
import Categories from '../data/categories';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Home = props => {
    const HeaderPart = (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.sectionSlider}>
                <CarouselSlider
                    data={CarouselSliderData}
                    height={width*0.6}
                    width={width}
                    itemWidth={width - (width/5)}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionFeatured}>
                <HeadingSecondary>Featured Products</HeadingSecondary>
                <FeaturedProducts data={MostSold} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionRecommendedCategories}>
                <HeadingSecondary>Recommended Categories For You</HeadingSecondary>
                <RecommendedCategories data={Categories} />
            </View>
            <HeadingSecondary>Recommended Products For You</HeadingSecondary>
        </ScrollView>
    );

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar />
            <View style={styles.sectionProducts}>
                <ProductList
                    data={MostSold}
                    numColumns={2}
                    key={'Products'}
                    ListHeaderComponent={HeaderPart}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    sectionSlider: {
        height: width*0.6,
        marginBottom: 12
    }
});

export default Home;
```

**components/UI/ProductList.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    FlatList,
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';

import ProductItem from './ProductItem';

const ProductList = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={props.data}
                renderItem={itemData =>
                    <ProductItem {...itemData.item} />
                }
                {...props}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

export default ProductList;
```

### Current Result Of Implementation

[image: Current Result]

### **What I Want to Accomplish**

[image: Aimed Result]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like wrapping the FlatList with ListHeaderComponent/ListFooterComponent properties inside a View component is not correct. I have updated my code to below and it's solved.

**screens/Home.js**

```
...
const Home = props => {
    ...
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar />
            <ProductList
                data={MostSold}
                numColumns={2}
                key={'Products'}
                ListHeaderComponent={HeaderPart}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
...
```